# Countability of collection of closed sets in $R$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, examples-counterexamples

Is the collection of all disjoint closed sets in $\mathrm{R} $ countable?

Comment: Consider single element sets.

Comment: What is a "disjoint closed set"? *Two* sets can be disjoint, i.e. $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if $A\cap B=\emptyset$, but how can *one* set be "disjoint"?

Comment: For clarity:  My reading of the question is "suppose we have a collection of disjoint closed sets in $\mathbb R$.  Must this collection be countable (or finite, for avoidance of doubt)?"  This is clearly true if you replace "closed" by "open" since each open set contains a rational and the rationals are countable.

Comment: Note:  the edit makes it worse.  The "set of all disjoint closed sets" has no apparent meaning.

Comment: Again:  To say you have a collection $\mathscr C$ of disjoint subsets of a given set means that $C_1,C_2\in \mathscr C\implies C_1\cap C_2=\emptyset$.  But a set on its own, without reference to any other set, can not be "disjoint".

Comment: @lulu I have edited now, sorry for inconvenience

Comment: The edit does not correct the error.  I understand what you are asking, or at least I think I do, but it's clear from the comments and posted solutions that others do not.  Look at my first comment.  Do you agree that that settles the issue?

Comment: Yes, it does. "Set of sets" phrase doesn't make any sense. I just posted in a hurry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a bit confused by your question, I'll try to answer to my interpretation of it.

It is true that *any* collection of open disjoint sets is countable. But it make no sense to consider the set of *all* closed (or open) disjoint sets (disjoint from what?). It is anyway not true that any collection of disjoint closed sets is countable, since it is enough to consider the collection of singletons, which are closed.